# .NET Core 3.1 - double.Parse removes dot

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to reduce the numbers of fractional digits in a double number

the function below works but removes the .

I tried with a , then the decimal part is gone

```
public static double PadAmount(double amount)
{
    try
    {
        string repr = amount.ToString("#.##");

        return double.Parse(repr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

thanks for helping me on this

Comment: Do you mean you test with 0,and you will get 0 rather than 0.00?

Comment: 0 is a weird case, it throws an error if the amount is zero, but I just want to turn 45.26817468 to 45.26...I removed it

Comment: I test with your code,and I will get 45.27.So you want to get 45.26?What do you mean `45.26...`?

Comment: I dont mind, what I do mind is that the . is gone...so it ruins my exports

Comment: I added a picture, so you can see the issue

Comment: Note that `.ToString("#.##")` doesn't have a culture specified.

Comment: it was in fact the toString that was introducing a ,

Comment: @phil123456 doubles are binary values, they have no dots or formats. Dots and formats apply to *strings*. Your code creates a string using your locale but tries to parse it back using the `InvariantCulture`. This is guaranteed to fail anywhere except the US (and China, if you don't do this on dates)

Comment: @phil123456 what's the point of this code anyway? Again, a `double` is a binary value, it has no spaces to pad

Comment: There's plenty of stuff that will break here. Whenever you convert to or from a string, you risk having issues unless you get the CultureInfo correct. Since you didn't pass a CultureInfo on ToString, the risk is that your default culture is different in formatting and will introduce issues, as you've already noticed. You could simply be doing `Math.Round(amount, 2)` to get what you want. However, a bigger issue is that .12 is not accurately representable by a `double` anyway, you'll get something like `.119999999999997442`. `.ToString` might still output .12, because of rounding, however.

Comment: If you don't want *rounding*, you can do `((int)(amount * 100)) / 100.0`, this will truncate away extra digits. It will still have the issue with accuracy, however.

Comment: this code as well as your purpose makes no sense at all. At first you format the number into a string of `45,12` (the comma `,` is used as the decimal point in your current culture). After that you parse back that string into a number but with `InvariantCulture` which treats the comma as a *group separator*. So in this case the value shown in debugging is just `4512` (group separator is just used in formatted strings for easily reading by humans).

Answer (score -2):

amount.ToString("#.##"); was introducing a , for some reason

```
repr = repr.Replace(",", ".");
```

Comment: That's the worst possible idea. `ToString()` isn't broken, the code is. This makes things **FAR** worse, as it can easily end up converting the fractional part into the integer part, resulting in a value 100, 1000  or in this case, 1M times larger

Comment: See the comment about missing cultureinfo being passed to ToString, and you should use `Math.Round` or something instead, to avoid roundtripping through a string, and then you should probably know that .12 is probably impossible to 100% accurately represent in a double anyway.

Comment: If you want localized formatting and parsing, specify the culture. NEVER, EVER try to cover up the problem by "replacing" decimal points that aren't broken. This has resulted in huge financial losses in the past. In 2012 [Knight Capital lost $400M in 45 minutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_Capital_Group) because of a similar bug

Comment: looks like you just wanted to format the value with `2` decimal digits. But you see the comma appears in the result and try to remove the comma. So actually it is affected by your current culture in the first place. What you need may be just something like this `amount.ToString("#.##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`